# Is there a way to tell whether a function parameter was passed as either a literal or as a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a function:

```
function hello(param){ console.log('param is '+param); }
```

And two calls. First:

```
hello(123)
```

Second:

```
var a=123; hello(a);
```

Is there any possible way to tell, from within the `hello` function, whether `param` was passed as a `var` or as a literal value?

NOTICE: I am not trying to solve a problem by this. There are many workarounds of course, I merely wanted to create a nice looking logging function. And also wanted to learn the boundaries of JavaScript. I had this idea, because in JavaScript we have strange and unexpected features, like the ability to obtain function parameter names by calling: `function.toString` and parsing the text that is returned.

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: Not on runtime, I'm afraid. You can parse the raw code and create an AST though. Then you'll be able to tell between a literal and a variable.

Comment: Sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)... What's the actual problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I am writing super convenient and neat logging function and I thought that js can do such things (for example in js you can detect names of function params by "toString"ing the func, so I thought maybe this thing is also possible...

Comment: Inside your `hello` function, all you have is the value.  You have no way to tell where it came from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, primitives like numbers are passed by value in Javascript. The value is copied over for the function, and has no ties to the original.

Edit: How about using an `object` wrapper to achieve something like this? I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly.

You could define an array containing `objects` that you want to keep track of, and check if its in there:

```
var registry = []  // empty registry
function declareThing(thing){  
   var arg = { value: thing }    // wrap parameter in an object 
   registry.push(arg)    // register object
   return arg;     //return obj
}
function isRegistered(thingObj){  
   return (registry.indexOf(thingObj) > -1)
}

var a = declareThing(123); 
hello(a);

function hello(param){ 
    console.log(isRegistered(param)); 
}
```

Comment: What is passing by value/ref has to do with it?

Comment: Well, it means that, regardless of where the value came from, it is copied over into a separate memory location. You end up with the exact same independent value either way.

If you were passing an object, for example, you could at least compare the original variable containing the same reference, and see that it is also stored there, rather than declared directly in the function argument.

Comment: @santi-elus, this is quite interesting, the trick with passing object! Could you please show example?

Comment: @santi-elus, I understand. But, all the OP wanted to know is whether the argument that is being passed to the function is a literal or not. Although you can (inside the function) compare the reference to another object, it assumes that the function has to know beforehand. The reason I wrote my comment is simply because even if `a` was `{}` (a reference type) you still wouldn't be able to tell that it's a literal.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that. I'm not sure exactly what OP is trying to accomplish here, so im just trying to offer any info that might be useful.